# React native and firebase push error

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

**Question**
I am very new to react native and firebase, and I am creating a simple app where you can upload text to the internet with firebase. When I added the code to use push to add a variable to firebase, I got an error, and I don't know why. I would love any help solving this problem. Picture of error is included at the bottom.

**Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableHighlight, Button } from 'react-native';

import { Font } from 'expo';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';


var fontLoaded = false;


var postRef = ref.child("posts");


var newPostRef = postsRef.push();


const firebaseConfig = {

 apiKey: "AIzaSyD025SWUH7zLELn4vWtf9nGq1-0h33Y958",

 authDomain: "candidtwo.firebaseapp.com",

 databaseURL: "https://candidtwo.firebaseio.com",

 storageBucket: "candidtwo.appspot.com",

};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


export default class App extends React.Component {


 state = {

    fontLoaded: false,

 };



 componentDidMount() {

     Expo.Font.loadAsync({

       'Cabin-Regular-TTF': require('./Cabin-Regular-TTF.ttf'),

     });

}

 constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = { postInput: ""}

 }

render() {

    return (

     <View style={styles.container}>

       <View style={styles.button}>

         <View style={{width: 1, height: 30, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />

         <Button

           onPress={() => this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })}

           title="Press Me To Load the App After 15 Seconds!"

           color="#fe8200"

           accessibilityLabel="Wait 15 seconds and then press me to load the font!"

         />

       </View>



       {this.state.fontLoaded ? (

         <View style={styles.container}>

           <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cabin-Regular-TTF', fontSize: 16 }}>

               Whats on your mind? Create a post!

           </Text>  


           <TextInput

                style={{height:40, width: 320, borderColor: '#303030', borderWidth: 1}}

                onChangeText={(postInput)=>this.setState({postInput})}

                value={this.state.postInput}    

            />



       <Button

      onPress={() =>

      

      newPostRef.set({

            content:this.state.postInput

      }); //Line 70, where the error occurred.

   

               this.setState({postInput: "Your post was succsesfully uploaded! :)" })    

    )}               

      title="                              +                              "

              color="#fe8200"

              accessibilityLabel="Wait 15 seconds and then press me to load the font!"

           />


           <ScrollView>

              <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />

              <View style={{width: 350, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1',  alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',    borderRadius: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight:10}} >

        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cabin-Regular-TTF', fontSize: 18, color: '#ffffff', textAlign: 'center'}}>

                   Why do android phones have higher inital quality than apple phones, but apple phones have a more consistent amount of quality throughout their years?

               </Text>

           </View>

              <View style={{width: 350, height: 40, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: '#147aa8', flexDirection: 'row',paddingLeft:5}} >

           <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/unlove.png')} />

           <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cabin-Regular-TTF', fontSize: 18, color: '#ffffff'}}>

                   3

                   </Text>

           <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/undislike.png')} />

           <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cabin-Regular-TTF', fontSize: 18, color: '#ffffff'}}>

                   1

                   </Text>

           <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/comments.png')} />

           <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cabin-Regular-TTF', fontSize: 18, color: '#ffffff'}}>

                   8

                   </Text>

       </View>

              <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />

              <View style={{width: 35, height: 25, backgroundColor: '#147c41', borderRadius: 10}} />

              <View style={{width: 35, height: 4, backgroundColor: '#0f582d', borderRadius: 10}} />

              <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />

          <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />

              <View style={{width: 35, height: 25, backgroundColor: '#9dcd46', borderRadius: 10}} />

              <View style={{width: 35, height: 4, backgroundColor: '#6c8f31', borderRadius: 10}} />

              <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />

          <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />

              <View style={{width: 35, height: 25, backgroundColor: '#d3832e', borderRadius: 10}} />

              <View style={{width: 35, height: 4, backgroundColor: '#935b1e', borderRadius: 10}} />

              <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />

      

            </ScrollView>

         </View>) : (null) }

     </View>

    );

 }

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 container: {

    flex: 8,

    backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',

    alignItems: 'center'

 },

 button: {

    flex: 1,

    backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',

    alignItems: 'center'

 },

});
```

**Error message**
[image: error message]

Comment: syntax error. looks like there is a extra closing parentheses `)}` after the `this.setState({postInput: "Your post was succsesfully uploaded! :)" })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your syntax error more then firebase problem

```
<Button
    onPress={() =>   <----- Here should add a open brackets
        newPostRef.set({ content:this.state.postInput }); //Line 70, where the error occurred.
        this.setState({postInput: "Your post was succsesfully uploaded! :)" })    
    ) <----- this should be a close brackets 
   /* some code... */
```

e.g. :

```
    <Button
      onPress={() => {
        newPostRef.set({ content:this.state.postInput }); //Line 70, where the error occurred.
        this.setState({ postInput: "Your post was succsesfully uploaded! :)" })    
      }}               
      title="                              +                              "
      color="#fe8200"
      accessibilityLabel="Wait 15 seconds and then press me to load the font!"
    />
```